# Laravel: Make the route dynamic based on the data

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing an experiment project where all the modules are dynamic.

I have module called MOdules where the user can add new modules

For example in my modules table I have the ff:

1. Products
2. Group

Im trying to create an dynamic route based on the modules that are added but can't die dump the variable in my route because I encountered error "Route [products.index] not defined."

```
$modules                    = ModulesEdited::get()->toArray();
foreach ($modules as $m => $module) {
    # code...
    $path_index = str_replace(str_split(' /\-='), '-', strtolower($module['module_name'])).'.index';
    /* =========================== DYNAMIC ROUTE =========================== */
    Route::middleware(['auth','subscription','accessrolemiddleware:'.$module->id])->group(function ($accesskey) {
        Route::get('/app/'.$module['module_name'.'/index',DynamicIndex::class)->middleware((['auth']))->name($path_index);
    });
}
```

Question: Is it possible to make the route dynamic based on the data inputed?

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` to see the registered route in your application

Comment: How do I pass the variable moulde insde of group?

Comment: you can add `use` after the function. `->group(function () use ( <YOUR VARIABLE> ) { /* your code */ })`